# Sum up duplicate rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql

### Mysql refuses to sum up duplicate row values

i have seen this query statement on a website but when i tried it mysql returns to me exactly what i have in my table without summing them up.ie.duplicate agent name and corresponding advance amount. Agent name and advance amount is a column. Agent_name has two records hitman and hitman. advance amount has two amount 40 and 20 for each Agent.

```
SELECT agent_name, 
SUM (advance_amount) 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY agent_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hoping the the same agent_name is based on different id  you could try using group by id

```
SELECT agent_name, 
SUM (advance_amount) 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY agent_id;
```